# Responsiveness to Mobile in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Im trying to make my bottom sheet responsive to mobile and desktop. you can see in laptop the bottom sheet when you click new topic it works all fine:

[image]

But then lets see it in a mobile version(On a regular Iphone 5):

[image]

You can see its beyond terrible... My HTML For that view is(Minimized):

```
<div class="toolbar_new_topic" ng-if="authDataDesc!=null">
  <md-button id="NEW_TOPIC_BUTTON" ng-click="showNewTopic($event)">
    <ng-md-icon icon="add_box" style="fill: white" size="20" id="add_icon"></ng-md-icon>
    <span id="text_new_topic" color="white">Create a New Topic</span>
  </md-button>
</div>
```

And my CSS Is:

```
.listdemoListControls md-divider {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.listdemoListControls md-list {
    padding-top: 0
}

.listdemoListControls md-list-item ._md-list-item-inner>._md-list-item-inner>p,
.listdemoListControls md-list-item ._md-list-item-inner>p,
.listdemoListControls md-list-item>._md-list-item-inner>p,
.listdemoListControls md-list-item>p {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}

body,
html {
    background: #DDD
}

#MD-ICON-1 {
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    bottom: -23px
}

.avatar_custom {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px
}

.avatar_creator {
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 30px
}

.toolbar_new_topic {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end
}

#NEW_TOPIC_BUTTON {
    background-color: #81C784;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-right: 50px
}

span.views_icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px
}

span.replies_list.md-secondary.ng-binding {
    position: relative;
    left: -55px;
    top: 18px
}

.user-avatar-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    min-width: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center
}

.tags a,
.tags li {
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 11px
}

.search_autocomplete,
input#input-0 {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: inherit
}

.tags {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 24px;
    bottom: -12px;
    list-style: none
}

.tags li {
    float: left;
    position: relative
}

.tags a:after,
.tags a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    float: left
}

.tags a {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 12px;
    background: #0089e0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px
}

.tags a:before {
    top: 0;
    left: -12px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent #0089e0 transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 12px 12px 12px 0
}

.tags a:after {
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #004977;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #004977;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 2px #004977
}

.tags a:hover {
    background: #555
}

.tags a:hover:before {
    border-color: transparent #555 transparent transparent
}

span.last_activity.ng-binding {
    position: relative;
    right: 129px
}

ul.tags {
    position: absolute;
    right: 1138px;
    bottom: 20px
}

span.bookmark_icon {
    position: relative;
    right: 130px;
    top: 1px
}

.user-avatar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%
}

md-list.ng-scope.md-whiteframe-24dp.flex-sm-55.flex-gt-sm-45.flex-gt-md-45 {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    background: #EF5350
}

md-list-item.md-3-line.ng-scope.md-clickable {
    background-color: #EF5350
}

.tags a {
    position: relative;
    left: 800px
}
```

Im currently Programming this website [here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm) so if you go there we can fix this problem real quick:
https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm

Thanks for your time!

Comment: your links ask for a login on both, so I can't see all of your code

Comment: Then Just Login? @mlegg it takes like a minute...

Comment: sorry I don't have an account, can you post all of the html and css on jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Answer (score 1):

You need to use media queries in your CSS to target mobile device sizes. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

Comment: ok... but that dosent help the actual problem. I want a fix for my problem, not a hint... and i was more attracted to flex i guess?

Comment: You said you wanted it to be 'responsive to mobile and desktop'. You cannot achieve responsive designs in CSS without media queries, so that's not a hint, it's the core of the answer you need. As for the rest, you'd need to be more specific in your question about the problem area and what you've tried, rather than just post a huge block of code and expect people to do the job for you.